# micro-outage of kubernetes worker node in mutualized kubernetes cluster using vcluster

Tags: kubernetes

I deployed a mutualized kubernetes cluster using "Vcluster".
Every 6 minutes, my worker node turn into "not ready" for few seconds. It can be showed in event section when I describe a pod or the node

```
Name:               k8s-wrk-poc02
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-wrk-poc02
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    tenant=poc-audit
Annotations:        kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket: /var/run/dockershim.sock
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    projectcalico.org/IPv4Address: 192.168.100.52/24
                    projectcalico.org/IPv4IPIPTunnelAddr: 10.244.41.64
                    vcluster.loft.sh/managed-annotations:
                      kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket
                      node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl
                      projectcalico.org/IPv4Address
                      projectcalico.org/IPv4IPIPTunnelAddr
                      volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach
                    vcluster.loft.sh/managed-labels:
                      beta.kubernetes.io/arch
                      beta.kubernetes.io/os
                      kubernetes.io/arch
                      kubernetes.io/hostname
                      kubernetes.io/os
                      tenant
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Wed, 06 Dec 2023 15:34:29 +0300
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:              Failed to get lease: leases.coordination.k8s.io "k8s-wrk-poc02" not found
Conditions:
  Type                 Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----                 ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  NetworkUnavailable   False   Wed, 06 Dec 2023 15:11:24 +0300   Wed, 06 Dec 2023 15:11:24 +0300   CalicoIsUp                   Calico is running on this node
  MemoryPressure       False   Fri, 01 Mar 2024 10:32:29 +0300   Wed, 06 Dec 2023 15:10:46 +0300   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure         False   Fri, 01 Mar 2024 10:32:29 +0300   Wed, 06 Dec 2023 15:10:46 +0300   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure          False   Fri, 01 Mar 2024 10:32:29 +0300   Wed, 06 Dec 2023 15:10:46 +0300   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready                True    Fri, 01 Mar 2024 10:32:29 +0300   Wed, 06 Dec 2023 15:11:16 +0300   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status. AppArmor enabled
Addresses:
  Hostname:    k8s-wrk-poc02.nodes.vcluster.com
  InternalIP:  10.101.129.165
Capacity:
  cpu:                2
  ephemeral-storage:  28204100Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             4019940Ki
  pods:               110
Allocatable:
  cpu:                1665m
  ephemeral-storage:  25992898517
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             3456740Ki
  pods:               101
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 b842abe479794e2e81d9bb276863299a
  System UUID:                a7a02242-9f3b-6e38-2724-f7f8f4322e27
  Boot ID:                    5422de95-8616-44ae-8e5b-6f74b76c3de9
  Kernel Version:             5.15.0-25-generic
  OS Image:                   Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  docker://20.10.14
  Kubelet Version:            v1.21.11
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.21.11
PodCIDR:                      10.244.11.0/24
PodCIDRs:                     10.244.11.0/24
Non-terminated Pods:          (7 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                              CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                              ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  cert-manager                cert-manager-webhook-8c7969b69-7zn76              0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         35d
  default                     nginx-deployment-84b8676f67-6cwth                 0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         35d
  kube-system                 coredns-68bdd584b4-zf89f                          3m (0%)       1 (60%)     16Mi (0%)        170Mi (5%)     76d
  kubernetes-dashboard        dashboard-metrics-scraper-6888846ddf-fdf9d        0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         35d
  kubernetes-dashboard        kubernetes-dashboard-5dcf4b9d9b-bjrhd             0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         35d
  monitoring                  prometheus-kube-state-metrics-65984858d6-p429q    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         35d
  monitoring                  prometheus-server-5d546c7886-zjm9s                0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         35d
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests   Limits
  --------           --------   ------
  cpu                3m (0%)    1 (60%)
  memory             16Mi (0%)  170Mi (5%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)     0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi      0 (0%)     0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)     0 (0%)
Events:
  Type    Reason        Age                      From             Message
  ----    ------        ----                     ----             -------
  Normal  NodeNotReady  4m30s (x21078 over 20d)  node-controller  Node k8s-wrk-poc02 status is now: NodeNotReady
```

I don't know what's the problem, I checked every logs, it shows nothing.

Any help?